# How to exclude items in Visual studio SQL schema compare based on string pattern or alternative

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-schema

We have a multi tenant system where each tenant has their own database. Tenants also have the option to create their own data structures which will be their own table in the database.

This causes an issue where when we run the visual studio schema compare it will always flag these tables as differences and we will have to unselect them. This becomes a big issue as the schema compare has major performance issues when unselecting multiple differences.

These user defined tables will all have a certain naming pattern e.g. **UserTable1,UserTable2** so what we really need is a way to perform the schema comparison while ignoring tables that contain a substring in this example it would be **UserTable**. Is this possible or is their a suitable alternative to using the Visual studio comparison tool?

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here from Google looking for a solution to this.

> All you have to do is right click on the section and ta-da, you can
>   Include or Exclude all objects depending on the existing state of the
>   objects.

In this case, section means the Delete, Change, and Add parent folders in the schema compare window.